# Stripe Subscription incomplete after 3DS check

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, sca

I'm not sure I understand this "new" Stripe SCA 3DS flow. When I successfully complete the 3DS authentication, create a customer, then the subscription, the subscription is marked as "incomplete".

This is my current Javascript implementation:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    disableFormSubmit(true);

    stripe.confirmCardPayment($('input#client_secret').val(), {

        payment_method: {
            card: cardElement,
            billing_details: {
                name: $('input#first_name').val()+' '+$('input#last_name').val(),
                email: $('input#email').val(),
            }
        }

    }).then(function(result){

        console.log(result);

        if (result.error) {
            disableFormSubmit(false);
            showPaymentError(result.error.message);
        } else {
            if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                disableFormSubmit(true);
                $('input#payment_method').val(result.paymentIntent.payment_method);
                form.submit();
            }
        }

    });
});
```

`confirmCardPayment` already takes care of the validation, showing me this overlay, where I click "Complete Authentication".

[image]

Following this, the customer (and payment method) is successfully created and a subscription is attached to the customer. But the subscription status now says "incomplete" with "requires_action". Now this is what I don't understand. Isn't the previous overlay responsible for this? According to the docs (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/set-up-subscription#manage-sub-status) I should call `confirmCardPayment` again, which I do not understand as I just did that, see JS code.

[image]

Why is my subscription still incomplete with a "requires_action" status even though I literally just completed this step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [part of the guide you're looking at](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/set-up-subscription#manage-sub-status) is about handling additional authentication actions and recovering from failed payments. You should only be providing the `client_secret` at this point:

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret)
```

In your code snippet, you're providing the `cardElement` again, when it was already [provided earlier](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/set-up-subscription#save-card-details):

```
stripe.createPaymentMethod({
  type: 'card',
  card: cardElement, // <-------
  billing_details: {
    email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
  },
})
```

I suspect something unexpected is happening because of this, so adjust your code to follow the flow of the guide and it should work.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Currently, I am not able to work with "fetch" or even clean Ajax calls due to the surrounding of the setup. I was not creating a payment method via the createPaymentMethod function, but rather the way it is described here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-submit-payment So I kind of have a mixture of direct payment and starting a subscription.

Comment: Hmm ok. Are you collecting payment up front? If so, try following the guide here [0]. If you're implementing with a trial or other deferred payment, it might be better to use the `pending_setup_intent` [1] with `confirmCardSetup` [2]

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/strong-customer-authentication#scenario-1-creation
[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-pending_setup_intent
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_card_setup

Comment: I was now able to use Ajax calls and was able to complete the flow. Everything seems to work fine, except that the customer is created two times when the first payment fails. But I guess I just have to store the customer id for the failed payment and update the customer later on.